# Remove or Hide Vertical Scrollbar in Fancybox 2.1.5

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, scrollbar, fancybox-2

I want to remove or hide the greyed-out vertical scrollbar when I am viewing pictures with FancyBox 2.1.5 on the following example page:

http://fancyboxtest.co.nf/

I've tried pretty much every solution found on google with zero results, can anyone please help...

Answer (score 2):

After you have loaded your fancybox css file, add this CSS declaration, either in inline in your page or inside a custom css file :

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Um7Ym/show/)**

Answer (score 0):

thanks JFK but someone suggested solving this by changing, in the **jquery.fancybox.css** file, the following:

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

into this

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and it worked perfectly ! thanks again

Comment: Well, I think messing with the original files is a bad idea because the day you update your original files, you would have to patch them again.... that won't happen with a custom css declaration. I hope "someone" stop suggesting bad practices ;)